# Why isn't the jquery .change() even triggering in subsequent events?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#calendarAppointmentStartTime').change(function() {
    $('#conflicts').empty();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
        if (sThisVal == "1") {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#resourceConflicts' + $(this).val()).empty();
        }
    });

    calculateScheduleEndTime();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
        if (sThisVal == "1") {
            conflictChecker($(this).val());
        }
    });
});​
```

The issue is as follows:
The first time the calendarAppointmentStartTime changes, the code is triggered. The second change also triggers but any subsequent change events do not seem to be triggering.  I cannot figure out what is happening.  It did work before I added the second $('#conflicts').html() and the first input checkbox iteration.

Can anyone see anything I might be missing? I could really use a fresh set of eyes.

edit:
 The relevant HTML for the checkboxes (there are a lot so I am only including 1:

```
<input id="Resource10" type="checkbox" onclick="conflictChecker(10)" value="10"name="resources">    
John Doe
<br/>
Conflicts:
<span id="resourceConflicts10">0</span>
```

and in another place:

```
<td>
<div id="conflicts"></div>
</td>
```

and the calendarstarttime input box:

The conflictChecker method adds content tot he conflicts div and disables the checkbox based on how many conflicts it finds for the relevant starttime.

Comment: The $('#conflicts').html() has been changed for $('#conflicts').empty().

Comment: Can you create a  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Please update the code in your question.

Comment: Could you include the relevant HTML for the page that the code is running against?

Comment: Please add the HTML-Markup to your questions. Without, we cannot see were potential problems are. Or even better: build a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: <input         id="calendarAppointmentStartTime" type="text" value="" />

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys!

I did work it out.  It came down to some logic I was missing in the use case.

The user could either click on checkbox to select a resource then change the time which would run the conflictchecker method. The conflict checker method would disable the checkbox and "uncheck" it based on an ajax return. Values would be set in the conflicts div based on the conflicts and in the resourceConflicts10 (the 10 changes based on the resourceID).  The second the starttime changes again, the code had to run another conflict check and enable all checkboxes and clear the notifications in the divs.

I was missing the fact that the conflicts caused the checkbox to be "unchecked"  so the following code:

```
var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
    if (sThisVal == "1") {
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#resourceConflicts' + $(this).val()).empty();
    }
```

needed to be changed to the following:

```
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#resourceConflicts' + $(this).val()).empty();
```

There were a couple of other changes but that is the one that got the changes working correctly.

Again, thanks everyone who volunteered to help. Now I'll just go smack myself for not originally going through each line and thinking a little harder about it before I posted a question. I feel like a dipstick now.